# I wonder that if the temporary object(name_compare()) is passed by value or by reference to std::sort

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, function-object

I wonder that if the temporary object(name_compare()) is passed by value or by reference to std::sort.

I would be thankful for any hint on this question.

```
 struct Record {
        string name;
        // ...
    };
    struct name_compare {   // compare Records using "name" as the key
        bool operator()(const Record& a, const Record& b) const
            { return a.name<b.name; }
    };
    void f(vector<Record>& vs)
    {
        sort(vs.begin(), vs.end(), name_compare());
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: You need to see how [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is declared. Does it declare the argument to be a value or a reference?

Comment: And please tell us *why* you wonder? Is there an underlying problem that makes you ask this question? What is the underlying problem? Please always ask about those directly.

Comment: The version of `std::sort()` that accepts three arguments that consist of a pair of iterators specifying a range and a comparator accepts all three arguments by value.

Comment: to pass by reference you have to have a declared object, here `name_compare()` is not declared, hence it will be moved and taken by value.

Comment: And I have a question for you. Why haven't you accepted Vlad's answer to the question you just asked? I see it answers your last question. How do you wait for an answer although you won't accept it?

Comment: @Some programmer dude I see.As per the documentaion aforementioned, i could draw the conclusion that it's passed by value.But it may cause extra waste(I mean it needs calll the default copy construction of `struct Record`  in `std::sort` ).So, i halt between two opinions.

Comment: @asmmo Sorry, i am new to this community.I have followed your advice.

Comment: @sunshilong369 I'm not sure why you think passing the comparator by value means that the copy constructor for Record must be called. Those two things have no connection at all.

Comment: Just looking at the signature of [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) would tell you it's passed by value. There's no `&` or `&&` on the parameter declaration.

Comment: @asmmo You mean temporary object could not be passed by reference.Am i right?
I would appreciate that if you could give me more information about it(related url is ok). Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @sunshilong369 A temporary object can be passed by reference. Happens all the time.

Comment: @john How and when?Could you give me a simple example?

Comment: Sure `void f(const std::string& s); f("abc");` a temporary `std::string` is constructed from `"abc"` and passed to the function `f` by reference. Note C++ does say that it must be a `const` reference for this to work. There's also the separate issue of r-value references. Those can also accept temporaries.

Comment: No it won't copy the `Record` structure, but it *can* cause a copy of the `name_compare` structure. And the compiler might omit (*elide*) that copy as well.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) deduces the `Compare` type and accepts it by-value:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

In most cases it means accepting the comparer by-value.

But that doesn't matter because

1. The comparer is usually an empty object with just a `operator()`, so passing it is practically a no-op;
2. The compiler can optimize away temporary object creation entirely;
3. Even if it isn't empty, copying one object once is negligible in relation to the sorting operation that will follow

In your case `struct name_compare` has no members, and so is an empty object.

It is possible to force deduction of the comparer type as a reference by wrapping it in `std::ref`.

By the way, a comparer doesn't have to be a class, it can be a `static` or a `friend` function, too:

```
struct Record {
    string name;
    static bool compare(const Record& a, const Record& b) {
        return a.name < b.name;
    }
    void f(vector<Record>& vs) {
        sort(vs.begin(), vs.end(), Record::compare);
    }
};
```

But better yet, you can rely on the built-in `std::less` implementation and simply define `operator<` for your type:

```
struct Record {
    string name;
    bool operator< (const Record& that) const {
        return name < that.name;
    }
    void f(vector<Record>& vs) {
        sort(vs.begin(), vs.end()); // operator < is used automatically
    }
};
```

Comment: Defining `op<` that way might be wrong. Still, it is an optin we cannot reject out of hand. As an aside, if it is actually uncopyable, `std::ref()` comes to the rescue.

Comment: @rustyx Since your answer, I could draw the conclusion that  it needs call the default copy constructor of `struct Record` in `std::sort`.Am i right?

Comment: `std::sort` uses [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), which uses move-construction when possible.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.I would dig deep.